# how to join products where seller distance <25

Tags: php, mysql, dictionary, distance

```
SELECT seller.id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( seller.latitude ) ) *
cos( radians( seller.longitude ) - radians('$log') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) *
sin( radians( seller.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance ,products.*
 from seller  LEFT JOIN products on seller.id=products.user_id where products.user_id=$sellerid
```

I want get seller from seller table and his distnce with its products from products table where seller distance is <25 or other
 how to do that? please help

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: just add `and distance < 25` at the end of your query ? The answer is in the question

Comment: At some point you're going to want to use [MySQL's spatial extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-types.html) instead of hand-rolled GIS code.

Comment: @Unex, Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause' When  add and distance < 25 at the end of your query How to specify column

Comment: Replace `distance` with `( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( seller.latitude ) ) *
cos( radians( seller.longitude ) - radians('$log') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) *
sin( radians( seller.latitude ) ) ) )`

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, HAVING distance<25 At Last Is answer

Comment: Don't post query that don't work.  How can you put `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`????